# Slack Events adapter not getting triggered

Tags: python, flask, slack, slack-api

I am trying to build a basic slack bot but the bot is not picking up the message event. Have added the following scopes: "chat:write"

Have also subscribed for the event message.channels.

I have configured ngrok server. When I hit the endpoint from my browser I get a message saying "these are not the slack bots you are looking for" which means the server is running. But when I post a message in the channel in which the bot is added, the API is not triggered. can you please help with this?

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
import slack_sdk
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask import Flask
from slackeventsapi import SlackEventAdapter

env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path = env_path)

app = Flask(__name__)
slack_event_adapter = SlackEventAdapter(os.environ['SIGNING_SECRET'],'/slack/events',app)

client = slack_sdk.WebClient(token = os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN'])

# client.chat_postMessage(channel = '#bi-announcements', text = "Hello World! ")

BOT_ID = client.api_call("auth.test")['user_id']

@slack_event_adapter.on('message')
def message(payload):
    print(payload)
    event = payload.get('event',{})
    channel_id = event.get('channel')
    user_id = event.get('user')
    text = event.get('text')

    if BOT_ID != user_id:
        client.chat_postMessage(channel= channel_id, text = text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here are the slack configurations:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm able to send messages to slack but not able to read the messages. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Did you invite your bot to the channel from where you want to capture the event?

Comment: Is the token configured in your code your `xoxp` token or your `xoxb` token? Make sure you're using the bot `xoxb` token.

Comment: @sandra Yes I'm using the xoxb token and it's still not working

Comment: @SuyashGaur Yes I have invited the bot to the channel from where I want to capture the event

Comment: Can you confirm the channel where you are posting the message is a 'public' channel ?

Comment: @SuyashGaur Yes the channel is a public one

Comment: Can you confirm in your ngRok console that your endpoint is not hit by the event?

Comment: @SuyashGaur Yes the endpoint is not hit by the event in ngrok

Comment: One more thing I noticed is that  you are using http instead of https in your endpoint. Can you change it to https and try again ?

Comment: @SuyashGaur Yeah I did try both but none of them worked. Strangely, I just created a new app altogether and changed the tokens in my code and it worked. I used the same configuration in my new app as well. Any idea what might have gone wrong there? But, the issue itself is now solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Strange! Maybe the first app was somehow compromised upon creation? Glad you have it working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, there was a rare occurrence that the created app somehow was faulty.

**Creation of a new app with same configuration solved the issue.**

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a new workspace and a new app as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).